# Ploting a function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, functions, boundary-conditions

I just ploted y[x],y'[x] but I would like to plot other function which is g[x] based on my solution but it can't plot this ??!!

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqn = {y''[x]/ y[x] + 1/2 (y'[x]/ y[x])^2 - 3 a/2 (y'[x]/y[x]) + k/2 (1/y[x]^2) - 3 f/2 == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{eqn /. {a -> 0.2, k -> 0.04, f -> 0.69}, y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 10}];
g[x] = 1 - a*y[x]/y'[x] - (k*y[x]^2)/(3 x^2*y'[x]^2) - f*y[x]^2/y'[x]^2;
Plot[g[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Comment: You have not assigned any numeric values to `a`, `f` and `k` in the Plot command.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I like using [`NDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html) better

```
eqn = {y''[x]/y[x] + 1/2 (y'[x]/y[x])^2 - 3 a/2 (y'[x]/y[x]) + 
     k/2 (1/y[x]^2) - 3 f/2 == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn /. {a -> 0.2, k -> 0.04, f -> 0.69}, 
    y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}];
g[x_] := 1 - 
   a*sol[x]/D[sol[x], x] - (k*sol[x]^2)/(3 x^2*D[sol[x], x]^2) - 
   f*sol[x]^2/D[sol[x], x]^2;
Plot[Evaluate[g[x] /. {a -> 0.2, k -> 0.04, f -> 0.69}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

> [image: plot]

---

**Original answer:**

---

```
eqn = {y''[x]/y[x] + 1/2 (y'[x]/y[x])^2 - 3 a/2 (y'[x]/y[x]) + 
     k/2 (1/y[x]^2) - 3 f/2 == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{eqn /. {a -> 0.2, k -> 0.04, f -> 0.69}, y[1] == 1, 
    y'[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 10}];
g[x] = 1 - a*y[x]/y'[x] - (k*y[x]^2)/(3 x^2*y'[x]^2) - 
   f*y[x]^2/y'[x]^2;
Plot[g[x] /. sol /. {a -> 0.2, k -> 0.04, f -> 0.69}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: I have Mathematica for Mac it's not giving me any plot!!!

Comment: @FelipeDura try to quit the kernel and start fresh. And please copy either the original or the edited answer I provided

Comment: thanks now it 's working

Comment: @FelipeDura glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 2):

FYI you can also ask [`NDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html) to return the function and it's derivative, e.g.

```
eqn = {y''[x]/y[x] + 1/2 (y'[x]/y[x])^2 - 3 a/2 (y'[x]/y[x]) + 
     k/2 (1/y[x]^2) - 3 f/2 == 0};
{sol, solp} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn /. {a -> 0.2, k -> 0.04, f -> 0.69}, y[1] == 1, 
    y'[1] == 1}, {y[x], y'[x]}, {x, 0, 5}];
exp = 1 - a*y[x]/y'[x] - (k*y[x]^2)/(3 x^2*y'[x]^2) - 
    f*y[x]^2/y'[x]^2 /. {a -> 0.2, k -> 0.04, f -> 0.69, y[x] -> sol, 
    y'[x] -> solp};
g[s_] := exp /. s -> x
```

and then plot

```
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}]
```

[image]